# Need to compare two tables (static_product table Vs order table) and put comparison result in new table with status insert/update/delete

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I've tried to use merge but need to put intermittent value in comparison table before actually merging data static_data into Orders table. (all tables are in same database )

ProductBundle can have multiple products in it and be added or deleted.
Orders that are placed with those productBundle has to sync up with latest product details in static_data table at end of day, this will help understand how many insert/updates/deletes are happening before actually merging this data

There are around ~500k records in Orders table and ~10k unique product records in static_data table

Can you suggest an approach

static_Data

```
ProductBundle   uniqueProductId     ProductName      
901             101                 Kane chair          
901             102                 Office chair        
901             103                 stool               
902             111                 study table         
903             121                 floor lamp          
903             122                 table lamp
```

Orders

```
OrderId     ProductBundle   uniqueProductId     ProductName
1           901             101                 Kane chair      
1           901             102                 Office chair    
1           903             121                 floor lamp      
                                                                
2           901             101                 Kane chair      
2           901             106                 sofa cushion    
2           902             111                 study table     
3           903             122                 table lamp
```

OrdersComparison

```
OrderId     ProductBundle   uniqueProductId     ProductName     Status
1           901             101                 Kane chair      update
1           901             102                 Office chair    update
1           901             103                 stool           insert
1           903             121                 floor lamp      insert
1           903             122                 table lamp      update
                                                                
2           901             101                 Kane chair      update
2           901             106                 sofa cushion    delete
2           901             102                 Office chair    insert
2           901             103                 stool           insert
2           902             111                 study table     update
                                                                
3           903             122                 table lamp      update
3           903             121                 floor lamp      insert
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: Don't copy data around between different tables. Create a view instead.

Comment: ok, but can single SQL help achieve it, or use cursor to iterate over each static record compare against orders data and evaluate if it's insert update or delete... need way to identify what'll happen before I merge it static data into Orders table ... or there's any other approach to get see what'll happen before actually merging it

Comment: I don't understand the output in `OrdersComparison`. Could you clarify ? e.g. how come `1           903             121                 floor lamp      insert` says `insert` ......and how the record `1           903             122                 table lamp      update` derived ?

Comment: Thanks for response @Sujitmohanty30  well Orders table has old data that needs to sync with Static data .... initially OrderId 1 had product 903 (which just had one entry with uniqueProductId =121 ) .... after a day static data got updated, now product  903 has two UniqueProductId=121 and 122 .... now need to update/replace existing 122 and as 121 is added to static_data, need to insert/add it comparison table/view .... comparison table should depict operation on Orders table based on records in Static_data table

Comment: @Rishi18 , which database are you using Mysql or Oracle and which version ?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30  it's Oracle 11g